# Setting up devise / mongomapper on Rails 2.3.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, mongomapper

I am trying to get basic authentication working using devise and mongomapper.
Following the instructions here:
http://johnwyles.com/2010/03/15/sessions-in-mongodb-using-mongomapper-and-devise/
(except deferring the routes.rb changes until after the generators are run to address errors)

I got it as far as getting the following paths to work:
/users/sign_up ::
/users/sign_in :: 
/users/password/new ::
/users/confirmation/new

However, just trying to hit "/" gives me an error

```
NameError in UserController#sign_in

uninitialized constant UserController
RAILS_ROOT: /Users/bentrevino/Documents/Dev/devisetest

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `load_missing_constant'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:80:in `const_missing'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:92:in `const_missing'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/inflector.rb:364:in `constantize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/inflector.rb:363:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/inflector.rb:363:in `constantize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:162:in `constantize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:444:in `recognize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:437:in `call'
```

After I submit a sign-up request, I get this error

```
RuntimeError in Registrations#create

Showing /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/devise-1.0.8/app/views/devise_mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb where line #5 raised:

Missing host to link to! Please provide :host parameter or set default_url_options[:host]
Extracted source (around line #5):

2: 
3: <p>You can confirm your account through the link below:</p>
4: 
5: <p><%= link_to 'Confirm my account', confirmation_url(@resource, :confirmation_token => @resource.confirmation_token) %></p>
```

Does anybody know what might be going on here?
Thanks!
Ben....

Comment: Did you ever solve the sign-up request error?  I followed the tutorial and added the following to config/environments/production.rb: config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {:host => 'mydomain.com'} but I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

At least one issue you are having is that you have not created a controller for your root route that you specified in config/routes.rb file.  Run a call to rails generate controller [name] to make a new controller.  Then specify that name in your config/routes.rb file for our root route.